# Adding database values from one pc to another

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am working on a database from two different computer, one person inserts data to the tables from one pc and another person from another. At the end of the day we want to add all the data inserted from 2nd pc to the 1st one. How can I achieve that?

I have tried exporting the database from 2nd pc and importing it on 1st pc but it doesn't work.

Comment: if you are using pc that is under one local network then you can share your database with every other pc available on the network.

Comment: Maybe,the problem is firewall or the second pc don't find the network

Comment: PCs are not connected.

Answer (score 0):

you said that you have tried to export the Database. I think that this is the thing to do. Export the Database as (SQL File) and import it on the other.

the steps to export your Database is:

go to your database location. For phpmyadmin its: localhost/phpmyadmin

navigate to your Database and select in the top Export.
make sure your Format is SQL!

to import it go to import and upload your file.